# How to get the count of buttons present on a webpage in selenium webdriver

Tags: list, xpath, selenium-webdriver, getelementsbyname

For eg: There is a list of flights displayed on a webpage. How to get the total  count of "Select" buttons displayed on that webpage

Answer (score 1):

When using the Java client bindings for example you can do something like that:

```
int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//a[.='Select']")).size();
```

Comment: not working .Used as it is.                     What xpath do I need to enter? I am getting the count as Zero which is incorrect

Comment: That depends on your web page. If you can't figure out a working locator for your elements, open another question which includes the HTML of the page.

Comment: Plz suggest some other method. If i have xpath of a complete frame which has buttons in it, how do i locate them

Comment: `//button[contains(text(),'Select')]` perhaps? So...`int count = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Select')]")).size();`

Answer (score 0):

snapshot of the problem would be really helpful. Yet trying to solve assuming you have list have fights displayed and trying to find count of select button. Probably 10 flights and 10 buttons

You can use Select class in selenium.

```
Select oSelect = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("Select")));
    List<WebElement> elem = oSelect.getOptions();
    int iSize = elem.size();
System.out.println("Count of select button " +iSize);
```